# How to pass value from a function to another function jQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have two functions.

```
var fileupload = document.getElementById("fileup");

        $('.upload-btn').on('click',function(){

           var sb_field = $(this).parent().find('input[type="file"]');

           sb_field.click();

        });


        fileupload.onchange = function (){

          var image       =    $('#fileup')[0].files[0];

        }


        $('.applyTeacher').on('click', function () {

          console.log(image);
}
```

When file upload.onchange function works I get the value in variable image and I want to use that value in the next function, but I am not able to do so. How can I pass this value?

Comment: Why not just look for it inside the click handler instead of in the `onchange`? Also better not to mix native methods and jQuery. Pick one approach and use it consistently.

Comment: I don't know about that, can you write that?

Comment: Just before `console.log(image)` put `var image       =    $('#fileup')[0].files[0];`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable globally:

```
var image="";
var fileupload = document.getElementById("fileup");

            $('.upload-btn').on('click',function(){

               var sb_field = $(this).parent().find('input[type="file"]');

               sb_field.click();

            });


            fileupload.onchange = function (){

              image       =    $('#fileup')[0].files[0];

            }


            $('.applyTeacher').on('click', function () {

              console.log(image);
    }
```